# Iambic Pentameter

Tags: poetry

[image]

I'm having some confusion with this rhythm. It's really hard for me to tell if a syllable is stressed or unstressed, accented or unaccented. I know what they are, but it's hard to do this in practice.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work.

Comment: Read the line with ridiculous stress where marked, giving equal time to each syllable, in a sing-song manner. Then reverse the pattern and read this. Which approximates more closely to a natural reading?

Comment: There is an exception in the example, right in the first line: the word 'and' gets stressed without an unstressed syllable before it. Say 'distant' quickly, then pause and say 'and', then you're back in rhythm. In performance, the sing-song quality is lessened, or the lines sound like a robot.

Comment: @Yosef: That's not an exception; the first syllable in *distant* is stressed; the second is not.